# Как запретить ввод отдельных строк по условию в Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet

У меня есть колонка, в которую вводятся только "да" и "нет", на основе нее хочу сделать возможность и невозможность изменять данные в строке, и сделать это с привязкой к конкретным пользователям.
То есть: особый пользователь ставит в A2 "да" и тогда весь ряд 2 можно редактировать. В A3 он ставит "нет", и тогда редактировать весь ряд нельзя. Кроме этого (этих) пользователей редактировать столбец А может только владелец документа.

Мне скинули базовый вариант скрипта, но почему-то он не работает. Все выполняется без ошибок, но эффекта нет. Помогите, пожалуйста, я совсем не знаком с js

```
   const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();  
   const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');     
   const checkA = sh.getRange('A2:A'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
   checkA.forEach( (ch,index) =>{                
       if (ch === 'no')
         {sh.getRange(index+2,2).protect()}});
}
```

Comment: Может, в ячейке надо написать `no`?

Comment: Да стоит, но только только толку нет)
Пример вот здесь 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VB-9f4hA1rkvEKekN4IiEbpXtFjY8DjHOAamBSRx1hU/edit#gid=0

Comment: А вы попробуйте `no` с маленькой буквы.